# How to remove <ul> in the navigation menu in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

The following code

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'container'          => '',
        'menu_id'            => 'primary-menu',
        'items_wrap'         => '<a class="mdl-navigation__link">%3$s</a>'
    )
);
```

will display an html code

```
<ul aria-expanded="false" class=" nav-menu">
  <li class="page_item page-item-2">
    <a href="http://localhost/gabriel/sample-page/">Sample Page</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

in the browser. What I want to do is, I'd like to remove `<ul>` and `<li>` wrapper in `<a>` Can you help me?

Comment: try searching for nav_walker in wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pass following argument in wp_nav_menu function
>   'container' => '','items_wrap' => '%3$s' .suggested from Martti Laine,Dannamite answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7968/how-do-i-remove-ul-on-wp-nav-menu

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread for options you have.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/customized-wp_nav_menu